# Comparing two objects except the pdo var

Tags: php, object, pdo

for my php project, I've created group objects which should be compared. Because they have a PDO connection stored in a variable, the == operator will always return false because one variable is not equal. Is there a way to compare these objects except comparing this one unique PDO variable?
The only way I could imagine would be a huge for loop which checks each variable.
I would be very happy if someone knows a smarter way.

Comment: You could use Reflection to compare each value except the one you know is different (i.e. the PDO connection)

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do? You're trying to compare two objects that are equal, **expect** for one **one property** that is different? Yes, the `==` operator will equate the two objects as false, because they're not identical objects. Are you trying to essentially loop over the properties of each object and check **how many** match?

Comment: @ObsidianAge The objects are exactly the same. I could make group() == group() and it could return false because the class sets the PDO connection to the database in the __construct() function. I'm looking for a way to compare these two and ignore the PDO connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function. It will use Reflection to compare every property except `$exceptParameter`

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $var1;
    public $pdo;

    public function __construct($var1, $pdo)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
}
$a = new Test("test1", "test2");
$b = new Test("test1", "test3");
$c = new Test("test2", "test4");
function areSameExcept($obj1, $obj2, $exceptParameter) {
    $ref1 = new ReflectionClass($obj1);
    $ref2 = new ReflectionClass($obj2);

    $propertiesObj1 = $ref1->getProperties();

    foreach ($propertiesObj1 as $propertyObj1) {
        if ($propertyObj1->getName() === $exceptParameter) continue;
        $propertyObj1->setAccessible(true);
        $valueObj1 = $propertyObj1->getValue($obj1);

        $propertyObj2 = $ref2->getProperty($propertyObj1->getName());
        $propertyObj2->setAccessible(true);
        $valueObj2 = $propertyObj2->getValue($obj2);
        if ($valueObj1 !== $valueObj2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
var_dump(areSameExcept($a, $b, "pdo")); // true
var_dump(areSameExcept($a, $c, "pdo")); // false
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Note: This solution only works for classes with no private properties.

You can make a class function that takes in another object from the same class and checks if all of the properties other than the PDO connection are equal.

There are two ways to do this, both of which require that you pass one of the objects as a parameter for the other object to compare with. You can either make a function that explicitly checks each property you want to compare between the two objects, or you can loop through the parameters and just skip past any parameters you don't want to check.

```
class GroupObj {
    public $prop1;
    public $prop2;
    public $prop3;
    public $db;

    public function __construct($prop1 = "", $prop2 = "", $prop3 = "") {
        $this->db = "connection established here";
        $this->prop1 = $prop1;
        $this->prop2 = $prop2;
        $this->prop3 = $prop3;
    }

    public function equalsTedious($object) {
        return ($this->prop1 == $object->prop1 &&
                $this->prop2 == $object->prop2 &&
                $this->prop3 == $object->prop3);
    }

    public function equals($object) {
        $result = true;
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            # skip properties you don't want to compare
            if ($key == "db") {
                continue;
            }

            if ($this->{$key} != $object->{$key}) {
                $result = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

$group1 = new GroupObj(1, 2, 3);
$group2 = new GroupObj(1, 2, 3);
$group3 = new GroupObj(4, 5, 6);

if ($group1->equalsTedious($group2)) {
    echo "Equal but annoying to maintain 1.<br>";
}

if ($group1->equalsTedious($group3)) {
    echo "Equal but annoying to maintain 2.<br>";
}

if ($group1->equals($group2)) {
    echo "Equal with the loop version too 1.<br>";
}

if ($group1->equals($group3)) {
    echo "Equal with the loop version too 2.<br>";
}
```

Comment: Ah, good point! I'll edit my answer to reflect that. I still want to leave it up in case someone wants a simple solution for a class with all public properties.